# ObjectiveC: Button press causes number to appear on screen?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to write a program in which the user presses a UIButton, and then the text of the button will appear within a UILabel. However, multiple buttons may instigate the resulting method, and therefore, the text within the label will change. I have a number key-pad that I created with buttons, similar to that of a phone, and then when a button is pressed, the number on the button will add itself to the end of the string in the UILabel. For example, if a "2" is pressed, a two will appear within the label. If a "3" button is pressed, the label will re-write itself to say "23." An example of my code for this is below:

```
NSString *str = [answerField text];
    if ([[sender titleLabel] isEqual:@"0"]){
    [str stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
    }
```

Logically, the code seems like it would work. answerField is the name of the UILabel, and if the button pressed has the label "0" as a string literal, I want to add the zero to the end of str. Unfortunately, when I run the program, nothing happens to the label. I can press a button, but the label does not change. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `sender.titleLabel` really an `NSString`? Or is it - deducing from its name - a `UILabel`? If it is, `isEqual:` won't return `YES`...

Comment: I am not sure... The sender is the object that is calling the method (in this case one of the numbered buttons from the keypad). I am trying to add the text on the button to the end of the text inside the UILabel, answerField. It seems that the comparison with isEqual is actually redundant, so I removed it from the code. However, I am still unsure as to how to add the button's text to the string in the answerField...

Comment: The sender is the `UIControl` that sends the action. Is that your `UIButton`? If so, is its `titleLabel` property an `NSString` or a `UILabel`?

Comment: Okay. I looked into it some more. The text on the UIButton (that is the sender) is stored in a property called currentTitle, which returns an NSString. I deleted my if-statements for every button, so that now when a button is pressed, it automatically adds its text to the string:

    NSString *str = [answerField text];
    NSString *newStr = [sender currentTitle];
    [str stringByAppendingString:newStr];
    [answerField setText:str];

But now I keep getting the exception that [str stringByAppendingString:newStr]; has a 'nil' argument?

Comment: if `titleLable` is really an `NSString`, even then you should not compare it to `@"0"` with `isEqual:` but with `isEqualToString:`

Comment: I got it working! Thank you so much for your help. I removed the isEqualToString comparison, because that comparison is inherent in the button being pressed. Instead, I found the issue was between comparing plain NSString with an NSAttributedString. I changed all of the text to plain, and now the comparison is working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the label's text to your new string... Also, the `if` statement seems unnecessary, you can just append whatever the `[UIButton titleLabel]`'s `text` is.

```
NSString *str = [answerField text];
str = [str stringByAppendingString:[[sender titleLabel] text]];
[answerField setText:str];
```

Comment: I apologize, but I forgot to mention that I do have the command [answerField setText:str]. However, when condensing my code to what you have posted, I get an exception that says that [sender titleLabel] is a nil argument...